# run internet explorer hidden even popups

Tags: internet-explorer, vbscript

I want to run Internet Explorer 8+ hidden. I know how to do it using vbs, my problem is that the popups does not run hidden. I dont want to stop the popups, i just want that the popups does not show visible, that runs hidden too.

I want to find a way to run even popups hidden or find a registry way (window_position?) to keep even popups hidden. But i repeat, i dont want to block them since i read information from that popups.

of course i need a way to revert this changes when needed in the case of registry.

Comment: Its too large. But the main problem is too short. Craerte a interbewt explorer using vbs and make it hidden, then go to any site that show a popup and the popup will be visible, na matter that the ie was hidden and i dont know how to avoid that, i want the popup to run, but invisible too.

Comment: Lets imagine a scenario: i click using vbs, in my hidden browser,in a link that opens in a new window, like a popup. It will be visible, no matter that the original internet explorer instance created by vbs was hidden:

Comment: Post the relevant bits.

Comment: Yes, exaclty. Popups shows visible no matter that the windows is hidden, there should be somewhere some way to avoid that.